# Redirect loggedIn Firebase user to Main Component with react-native-router-flux

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, firebase-authentication, react-native-router-flux

I'm trying to direct the user to Main Component every time the app starts up.

I use react-native-router-flux as my navigation wrapper, Firebase as backend and Redux as state management library.

Here's the problem. I do `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` in my Router Component to determine whether the user is loggedIn.

If there is no user, then return Login component.

If there is a user logged in, return Main Component, as the base component in the stack.

This [SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687199/react-native-redirect-logged-in-firebase-user-to-home-component) has the exact problem and the answer proposed suggests using [Switch Feature](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/OTHER_INFO.md#switch-new-feature) from react-native-router-flux. I gave it a shot, not helpful.

Here is my code.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'
import reducers from './reducers';

import Router from './Router';

class App extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    firebase.initializeApp({
      //my firebase config
    });
  }

  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Router.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { isLoggedIn } from './actions';
import { Scene, Router, Actions, Switch } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import firebase from 'firebase';

import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import Register from './components/auth/Register';
import Main from './components/Main';

class RouterComponent extends Component {

  state = { loggedIn: false }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.isLoggedIn();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Router sceneStyle={{ }} hideNavBar={true}>
        <Scene key="root">
          <Scene key="authContainer" initial>
            <Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login Page" />
            <Scene key="register" component={Register} title="Register Page" />
          </Scene>

          <Scene key="mainContainer">
            <Scene key="main" component={Main} title="Main Page" />
          </Scene>
        </Scene>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(null, { isLoggedIn })(RouterComponent);
```

**Some of my redux action creators**

```
export const isLoggedIn = (dispatch) => {
  return(dispatch) => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user));
  };
};

const loginUserSuccess = (dispatch, user) => {
  dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
    payload: user
  });
  Actions.mainContainer({ type: 'reset'});
};
```

I understand the exact motivation can be achieved with the async snippet below:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // return <Main />
  } else {
    // Stay at login screen
  }
});
```

but I'm trying to recreate it with react-native-router-flux.

Here's a gif-shot of my app to help you guys understand more. 
A user has already logged in. The Main screen is being dispatched after some time. Any thought?
[image: GIF]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there are any specific constraints in your app but I'm using a **Splash** screen (also disable the default one generated by Xcode) and perform authentication checking on this screen.

If user logged in, reset the stack to **Main** component, otherwise reset the stack to **Login** component.

Comment: Yeah this approach just came to my mind just now but it didn't resolve the root cause did it? :)

Comment: You set **Login** component as the initial route, so whenever your app is launch, you will see **Login** screen instantly. Implementing a **Splash** screen is a common practice and user friendly too.

Comment: @datnt do you have any source of tutorial for learn how to add this ? I get the same error.

Comment: @EQuimper To add a splash screen, you can create a new Container/Screen and make this as your initial screen instead of the one you are using. 
However, in order to remove the default Launch screen (iOS only) you need to open Xcode. There are many tutorials show how to remove this Launch Screen you can search on SO or Google.