# Redirect to the page if already signed in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router, firebase-authentication

I have put a google authentication in my page. Now, Once I
log in, the session should be persisted if the app's tab is closed, and when I return, should automatically login again. It's not happening here,
any help ?

I'm having the following things

**/* index.js */**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import Routes from './routes';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

// Initialized Firebase here

var config = {
    apiKey: "<api key>",
    authDomain: "<auth domain>",
    databaseURL: "<database url>",
    projectId: "<project id>",
    storageBucket: "<storage bucket>",
    messagingSenderId: "<messaging sender id>"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

// Have set the route here

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={Routes} />,
    document.querySelector('.container')
);
```

**/* login.js */**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    static contextTypes = {
        router: PropTypes.object
    }

    handleClick() {
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();;
        let self = this;
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
          self.context.router.push("/postsfeed");
        }).catch(function(error) {
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="sign-in-div">
                <button className="sign-in-button" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
                    Sign in with Google
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

**/* postsfeed.js */**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

class PostsFeed extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <div>Posts Feed</div>
        );
    }
}

export default PostsFeed;
```

**/* routes.js */**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import Login from './components/login';
import App from './components/app';
import PostsFeed from './components/postsfeed';

export default (
    <Route path="/" component={App} >
        <IndexRoute component={Login} />
        <Route path="postsfeed" component={PostsFeed} />
    </Route>
);
```

**/* app.js */**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.children}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687199/react-native-redirect-logged-in-firebase-user-to-home-component

Comment: Show us your routes code

Comment: yes, shown the routes code.

Comment: also added the **app.js** and **index.js** code